# Crashes Back (WriteableBitmap cannot be serialized) windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When I choose to complete the first page photo
Change to the second page of the selected photo will crashes Back

I have read this post

[Crashes Back to AppPage from Home ('System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized) WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744566/crashes-back-to-apppage-from-home-system-windows-media-imagesource-cannot-be)

but I don't know how to deleting BitmapSource Property

this is my code

```
PhotoChooserTask pc;
BitmapImage finalImage;

pc = new  PhotoChooserTask();
pc.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(pc_co);


  public void pc_co(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {


        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {

            finalImage = new BitmapImage();
            finalImage.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            img.Source = finalImage;

        }

    }
```

and Crashes Back message

```
exception  {System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.
```

Comment: Same symptoms, same cause. You've stored at some point an ImageSource in the phone state (probably PhoneApplicationService.Current.State or IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings). You have to find where!

Comment: Thanks for help!!! I found it