# Could not call the secondary tile page to show correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

#### Purpose

I want to use secondary tile in my application that can pin the page to the start menu, and when the user click it show the page correctly.

#### Problem

The page that the user trying to pin to the start up menu contains the information needed to receive from the previous page; therefore, if the page is pinned to the start up menu, and is navigated directly to it, it will not receive all neccessary information to show on the page.

To store the information sent from page to page, I use **PhoneApplicationService.Current.State** to store the data that need to send to the next page. That data is the selected item from listbox.

#### My Sample Code

Here is the code that is to select item from the listbox to store, and sent to the next page

Product List.xaml.cs

```
namespace App_Skin_Test_Final_.All_Files.Product_Files
{
    public partial class Product_List : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string pro_list_id;
        public Product_List()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            // =====================================   Add Search application bar   =====================================
            // Show application bar
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

            // Search Application bar
            ApplicationBarIconButton btnSearch = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            btnSearch.IconUri = new Uri("/images/Icon Application Bars/Search.png", UriKind.Relative);
            btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(btnSearch);
            btnSearch.Click += btnSearch_Click;

        }
        // function Search application bar
        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Search.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }


        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("pro_list_id", out pro_list_id))
            {

            }
        }

        private void lst_product_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            //MessageBox.Show(pro_cate_id);
            XDocument data = XDocument.Load("All Files/Database XML/ProductsDry.xml");
            var productListData = from q in data.Descendants("DryCategory")
                                  from itemDry in q.Elements("ItemDry")  // mean: itemDry in in DryCategory
                                  where q.Attribute("DryCategoryId").Value == pro_list_id
                                  select new ProductsDry
                                  {
                                      ItemDryName = itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryName").Value,
                                      ItemDryImage = getImage(itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryImage").Value),
                                      ItemDryId = itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryId").Value,
                                      ItemDryIngredients = itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryIngredients").Value,
                                      ItemDryDesc1 = itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryDesc1").Value,
                                      ItemDryDesc2 = itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryDesc2").Value,
                                      ItemDryUse = itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryUse").Value
                                      //            ItemDryLink=itemDry.Attribute("ItemDryLink").Value
                                  };


            lst_product.ItemsSource = productListData;

            //   NavigationService.GoBack();
        }

        private System.Windows.Media.ImageSource getImage(string p)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(p, UriKind.Relative));

        }


        private void lst_product_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lst_product.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myimage"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryImage;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryIngridient"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryIngredients;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryUse"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryUse;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc1"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryDesc1;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc2"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryDesc2;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryUse"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryUse;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?&pro_name=" + (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryName + "&pro_image=" + (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryImage, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else return;
        }

        private void btnGoBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            {
                this.NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the page to receive selected item information from the previouse page "Product List.xaml" and it is the page that I want user to pin specific product that they have selected.

Product Detail.xaml.cs

```
namespace App_Skin_Test_Final_.All_Files.Product_Files
{
    public partial class Product_Detail : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string pro_name;
        string pro_image;
        string pro_ingridient;
        //string pro_link;
        string pro_use;
        string pro_dryDesc1;
        string pro_dryDesc2;
        // ImageSource image;

        private readonly string SecondaryTileUriSource = "Source=SecondaryTile";

        public Product_Detail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            // =====================================   Add Search application bar   =====================================
            // Show application bar
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

            // Search Application bar
            ApplicationBarIconButton btnSearch = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            btnSearch.IconUri = new Uri("/images/Icon Application Bars/Search.png", UriKind.Relative);
            btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(btnSearch);
            btnSearch.Click += btnSearch_Click;

            ApplicationBarIconButton btnPin = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            btnPin.IconUri = new Uri("/images/Icon Application Bars/pin.png", UriKind.Relative);
            btnPin.Text = "Pin";
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(btnPin);

            btnPin.Click += btnPin_Click;
     
        }

        void btnPin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // secondary tile can be created only as the result
          // of user input in an application

            ShellTile tile = this.FindTile(SecondaryTileUriSource);
            if(tile==null)
            {
                //because the UI will navigate to Start
                //When a new secondary tile is created
                //only one secondary tile can be created at a time
                StandardTileData tileData = this.GetSecondaryTileData();

                MessageBox.Show("The SecondaryTileUriSource is " + SecondaryTileUriSource);
                
                //having a unique NavigationUri is necessary for distinguishing this tile
                string tileUri = string.Concat("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xmal?", SecondaryTileUriSource);

             //   MessageBox.Show("the uri is " + tileUri);
                ShellTile.Create(new Uri(tileUri, UriKind.Relative), tileData);

              //  ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml", UriKind.Relative), tileData);
            }
        }
        // function Search application bar
        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Search.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            // Check if the Secondar tile exists 

            ShellTile secondaryTile = this.FindTile(SecondaryTileUriSource);

            if (secondaryTile != null)
            {

         // *****************************************************      tile.Delete();
                MessageBox.Show("Secondary tile exist.");
            }



            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("pro_name", out pro_name))
            {

            }
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("pro_image", out pro_image))
            {

            }
            txtbPro_Name.Text = pro_name;

            BitmapImage bm = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myimage"] as BitmapImage;
            img_Product.Source = bm;

            // Ingridient Text
            pro_ingridient = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryIngridient"] as string;
            txtb_ingridient.Text = pro_ingridient;
            // Find on Somaly store
            //pro_link = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryLink"] as String;
            //txtb_link = pro_link;


            // How to use product
            pro_use = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryUse"] as string;
            txtb_howToUse.Text = pro_use;

            // Description 1 and Description 2
            pro_dryDesc1 = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc1"] as string;
            txtb_description1.Text = pro_dryDesc1;
            pro_dryDesc2 = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc2"] as string;
            txtb_description2.Text = pro_dryDesc2;



            // txtb_ingridient.Text = pro_image;
            // image = getImage(pro_image);
            // MessageBox.Show(image);
            // img_Product.Source = image;



        }

        private ImageSource getImage(string img)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(img, UriKind.Relative));
        }



        /*********************************************
         * Create a Secondary Tile for pin application
         *********************************************/

        private StandardTileData GetSecondaryTileData()
        {
            StandardTileData titleData = new StandardTileData
            {
                Title = "Secondary Tile",
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/Allures/Base/aba001.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                Count = 5,
                BackTitle = "Secondary Tile",
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
                BackContent = "WPG Add Remove Tile Sample"
            };
            return titleData;
        }
        private ShellTile FindTile(string partOfUri)
        {
            ShellTile shellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(
                title => title.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(partOfUri));
            return shellTile;
        }
          
   


    }
}
```

When the user presses on pin application bar button on the Product Detail.xaml page, the page is pinned to the start up menu as normal; however, when they press on pinned page at the start up menu, it never navigate back to the Product Detail page. But if I comment out every line of PhoneApplicationService.Current.State in product detail.xaml.cs, it could navigate to the page but it does not show anything on the page, the information on the selected item.

How can I correct this error to show the page that the user pin to the start as normal?
Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct issue is that when launching the app from the secondary tile, the values in the PhoneApplicationService.Current.State dictionary are not populated, so you cannot read them.

But even if you get around that and find out why the state is not populated, I see a bigger problem in the code. I imagine that you show a list of products, and can navigate to the details of each product, and want to allow the user to pin a specific product to the Start page. So, imagine that you store the selected product in the phone state dictionary and then pin the details. The you open the application and select another product - so it will be now stored in the app state, and tapping the pinned tile will open the second product details ...

My suggestion is to redesign the interaction between the pages - if you have some unique id that can identify the products, pass that id to the product detail page, and also store that same id in the uri of the secondary tile, like this: 
   new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?&item_id=" + itemId)

Then, in the OnNavigated() method of the product details page, read the id from the query string, then access the full list of products, locate the product with that id, and display it.
This way all navigations - from secondary tile, resuming the application, etc. will work correctly.

Comment: very thanks for helpful answer. I could fingure out that I would make an if condition to check whether the detail page is navigated from page to page or from the secondary tile. Yes, each product has the unique id and all information about product are store in xml file as my database, I will change to them that as now I pass to product detail page the product name. I know it is the limitation of the secondary tile that allow only one page to be pinned to the start up menu, so it will be even more problem if the user has more than one favorite product to be pinned. Anyway,thanks again :)

Comment: @user2273145 "I know it is the limitation of the secondary tile that allow only one page to be pinned to the start up menu" - no, you can create as many secondary tiles as you want provided each has unique uri associated. So, you can allow the user to create secondary tiles for each products, by including the product id in the uri.

Comment: @Jogy-I could navigate to page detail from secondary tile for the first time, but from the second time on ward, it show error at ` string SecondaryTileUriSource = "item_name=" + PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_name"] as string;` with the message "KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code. The given key was not present in the dictionary." what's wrong?

Comment: @user2273145 You'd better not rely on PhoneApplicationService.Curretn.State at all - instead you should pass the item name in the navigation parameter for the page.

Comment: I settled it by using `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` because I want to store data permenantly until the user remove application from device or rebuild project from emulator. Anyways, I met the problem with sending image to detail page. At first open, it showed the image, but when I pinned the page, it showed error ** System.Windows.Media.ImageSource cannot be serialized**. I found some resources said that we could not serialize the ImageSource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335043/windows-phone-8-imagesource-cannot-be-serialized-error-while-sharing-image

Comment: but it still could not solve. How can I handle with image serialized? Can I use uri parameter to send image without serialized problem? From some source, they said we should not sending an image but instead the parth of the image as the string and then convert it to BitmapImage, but I don't know how to get the image full path. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: @user2273145 I see that you have a method in ProductList page: private System.Windows.Media.ImageSource getImage(string p). SO, you have a way to load image by name. I suggest to move all data loading related methods in a central place that is accessible by all pages. For example you can make static methods in the App class. This way you will not have to use the any state objectes to pass data internally between pages in the application

Comment: @Jogy-that you meant the method getImage(string p) is not accessible by other page and need to move this method to App.xaml.cs? I will try this and let you, thanks

Comment: @user2273145 Yes, exactly. Keep in mind that especially when starting the application from a secondary tile which navigates directly to the product details page, the product list page will not be created at all, so you should not rely on any code from it executing. The same can happen when the app is tombstoned and then resumed - only the last active page will be created.

Comment: @Jogy-really appriciate for comment. I got an idea out of that, however, I don't know how to put it into implementation at all. Since in fact it is my first project on windows phone, I would need some times to look into app.xaml.cs. Could you give me any link tutorial reference to it? or I will search it.

Comment: @user2273145 app.xaml.cs contains the code for the App class which is the main class for the application and is always created. You can access it from any page like this: App app = (App)Application.Current. So, you can put all your data-related methods there.

Comment: I have moved all related data in getImage() method into app.xaml.cs and called it as you said.I passed an image as part of uri parameter and receive it by using NavigationContext.QueryString and convert it to BitmapImage using getImage(NavigationContext.QueryString["pro_image"]) but the image still not display. One way, can I convert an image to string by encodeBase64 before I pass it as part of uri to next page so that I send an image string instead of image object, and convert it back to image object on the next page? if it can, can you show me by coding example?

Comment: @user2273145 Have you checked if getImage(NavigationContext.QueryString["pro_image"]) works and returns the correct image? And then how are you displaying the image?

Comment: I updated the uri navigation as ` NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?&pro_name=" + (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryName + "&pro_image=" + (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryImage.UriSource, UriKind.Relative));` by this way I send the image uri source instead of image object, and I receive and set the image to display as `  IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("isolated_image", NavigationContext.QueryString["pro_image"] as string);`

Comment: and `item_image.Source = ((App)Application.Current).getImage(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["isolated_image"] as string);` . Then the image is show as normal. However, when I tried to pin the page, I still got the error **Could not serialize imageSource** . I am sure that I did not serialize the image but the Uri Source of the image and convert it to BitmapImage using getImage() method, and I don't know why still this error.

Comment: @Jogy-I'm very pleased to let you know that now I could display the secondary tile correctly. Actually, your very first answer was all correct! There are mainly two problems in this. First problem is on serialization problem, it took me almost a week to found the root cause of this error. The error is at my VM ProductsDry.cs. In it before, I set ItemDryImage data type as BitmapImage and ImageSource which was the object that could not be serialized. To solve this, I changed its data type to string then it worked fine.

Comment: So, I could pin the page and show the image without any error. However, my second problem is when I pinned more than one secondary tile at the start menu, then all the secondary tiles took the same content as the last secondary tile that I pinned. Ex. first and second secondary tiles when I press on any of them it show the same content like the third secondary tile. This is like you mentioned **"But even if you get around that and find out why the state is not populated, I see a bigger problem in the code. I imagine that you show a list of products....."**

Comment: To solve this, instead of passing the image name to the image uri, I set the uri of image like `Uri uri = new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?&id="+idd,UriKind.Relative);`Then, I query all product information from xml file, and use foreach loop to loop through that query result and find the image for that specific id`   foreach(ProductsDry list in productListData)
            {
                if(list.ItemDryId==idd)
                {
                    imageBase = list.ItemDryImage;
                    imageBase = imageBase.Substring(9);
                }
            }`

Comment: Finally from image path I got from foreach loop, I convert it to base64 encoding string, and then convert it back to image bitmapimage. By this way, I could differentiate any secondary tile content and show all information correctly according to the product detail that I pin. :)